# Is it grammatically correct to use full sentence when answering questions instead of using only auxilliary verbs?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Is it correct and natural to reply to the question

> *Do you have any cars?*

by saying the following?

> Yes, I have some cars.

Does it always have to be the short form?

> *Yes I do*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers that you suggested are equally acceptable. The length of the answer depends on several factors:

- the mood of the persons (especially the one who answers);
- the temperament of the speaker; extroverts will tend to talk more;
- the state of emergency (long answers are not suitable in cases of danger);
- the need of detail;
- formal vs. informal: formal answers tend to be longer, sometimes. Compare: "Yes, we have." with "Aha!";
- the requirement of the job; a sales person will probably provide the entire description of all portfolio of products, plus prices and payment options, together with the "Yes";